# How to compile python with PyInstaller in Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pyqt, pyinstaller

I am using `Python 3.5.2` , `PyQt 5.7` , `PyInstaller 3.2` and I'm in Linux

I can compile file.py with : `pyinstaller file.py`

but when I run the binary file in Build folder it returns:

`Error loading Python lib '/home/arash/build/file/libpython3.5m.so.1.0': /home/arash/build/file/libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Where is the python library (.so file) to copy inside binary file or PyInstaller flag for copy library file?

Comment: yes i read documentation, where is libpython3.5m.so.1.0 file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the binary file is in the `dist` folder not `build` folder

Answer (score 0):

If this is just about the location of that .so; see here:

```
/usr/lib/python3.5 $ find . -name "*.so" | grep libpython
./config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5.so
./config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so
```

Another way to find it would be by running

```
> locate libpython3.5m.so
/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so
```

...

In other words: it should be part of the python3.5 installation of your system. Probably you can just copy it from there for further experiments.